# "Condition expected" error when trying to nest CASE WHEN THEN statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

The code before my changes (working perfectly well):

```
CASE WHEN b.EPIdentifier IS NOT NULL THEN b.EndTime
```

My changes when trying to implement some further nesting CASE WHEN THEN logic:

```
CASE WHEN b.EPIdentifier IS NOT NULL THEN 
    CASE WHEN b.CancelEndTime IS NOT NULL THEN
        b.CancelEndTime
    ELSE CASE WHEN b.ExtendedEndDate IS NOT NULL THEN
        b.ExtendedEndDate
    ELSE CASE WHEN b.EndTime IS NOT NULL THEN
        b.EndTime
ELSE a.EndDate END EndDate
```

I get an error on the very last `EndDate`:

> an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

I can't figure out why I'm getting the error. I've tried to put `AS EndDate` instead but I still get the same error. Have I messed something up with the nesting? I can't spot anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put an `END` on every `CASE WHEN`. Your expression should be something like this:

```
CASE WHEN b.EPIdentifier IS NOT NULL THEN 
    CASE WHEN b.CancelEndTime IS NOT NULL THEN b.CancelEndTime
    ELSE CASE WHEN b.ExtendedEndDate IS NOT NULL THEN b.ExtendedEndDate
         ELSE CASE WHEN b.EndTime IS NOT NULL THEN b.EndTime END
         END
    END
ELSE a.EndDate END EndDate
```

Anyway you can simplify your expression using [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
CASE WHEN b.EPIdentifier IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(b.CancelEndTime, b.ExtendedEndDate, b.EndTime)
ELSE a.EndDate END EndDate
```

From **MSDN**:

> The COALESCE expression is a syntactic shortcut for the CASE expression. That is, the code COALESCE(expression1,...n) is rewritten by the query optimizer as the following CASE expression:

```
CASE

   WHEN (expression1 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression1
   WHEN (expression2 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression2
   ...
   ELSE expressionN
END
```

Comment: Of course I'm missing the END how could I miss that. That's a nice simplification. Are there any drawbacks in using COALESCE over case statements? Performance wise.

Comment: @D.Singh check the edited answer. `COALESCE` is just a shortcut that will be translated in a `CASE WHEN` expression.

Comment: It works now perfectly and I've learnt some new syntax! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> END is the Part of CASE Statement, so you have to lookup for END.

SYNTAX FOR CASE Statement :
[SQL CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
Simple CASE expression: 
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END 
Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```